# How to set the Background image for KendoUI Page

Tags: kendo-ui

I am using Kendo ui.

My Page layout consist of Splitter bars, Panel Bars and Grids.
I want to provide the Background image for the whole page.

I have tried using the following but no background image is displayed. 
The Path for the Image is correct and verified

```
body
{
background-image:url('xxxxx.jpg');

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to find the CSS selectors for all the Kendo UI elements and set `background-color: transparent` on them.